# Detecting if Safari App Extension is installed and enabled

Tags: macos, safari-app-extension

I have a Safari App Extension. Is there a way to detect *from the containing app* if the extension was successfully installed and enabled in Safari? The documentation leaves a lot to be desired…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally the way to check is through **[`SFSafariExtensionState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionstate?language=objc)** and **[`SFSafariExtensionManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager?language=objc)** — if it's enabled, then it's installed.

**Example**:

```
let extensionIdentifier = "com.acme.MyAppExtension"

@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var statusImage: NSImageView!

func checkAppExtension() {
    SFSafariExtensionManager.getStateOfSafariExtension(withIdentifier: extensionIdentifier) { (state, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if (state?.isEnabled ?? false) {
                self.label.stringValue = "MyApp Extension for Safari is enabled"
                self.statusImage.image = NSImage(named: "enabled")
            } else {
                self.label.stringValue = "MyApp Extension for Safari is currently disabled"
                self.statusImage.image = NSImage(named: "disabled")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha! I must have missed that one, thank you! The API is a mess.

Comment: You're welcome, there's also [`SFSafariExtensionManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariextensionmanager?language=objc) which is similar, but can include an identifier and completion handler.

Comment: Well, I have missed that one _too_. So I guess my reading skills are a mess, not the API. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any way to get notified about state changes of the extension? The guys at AdBlock are doing it somehow, but I don't know if they constantly check for state or they are somehow notified when it's enabled/disabled.

Comment: Is there anything similar to iOS?